# Windows (steam) games

Tags: linux, games, steam

So I recently got a new computer and switched from windows to manjaro, and I, of course, can't play some of my games I bought on steam (I can't even attempt to install them because the install button is gone). I was told to download wine + other add-ons for wine, didn't do anything. Is there anyway I can play these games? (Keep in mind I'm new to Linux)

Comment: Most of them require specific settings related to the given software. [There](http://portwine-linux.ru/) are instructions, how to play some windows or steam games on Linux. (Although the main page is on Russian, there is a language selector widget on the left.)

Answer (score 6):

To install and run Windows games using Steam and Wine, you need to install Steam *in* Wine. You need to [download the Steam client for Windows](http://store.steampowered.com/), install it using Wine, and connect to your Steam account. (You won't be able to run both the Linux and Windows clients simultaneously.) Then you'll have access to your Windows games from the Steam client running in Wine, and you'll be able to install and run some of them.

Not all Windows games work well using Wine. You'll find compatibility information, bugs and workarounds in the [Wine AppDB](https://appdb.winehq.org/).